# How to retrieve data from Postresql query which consist of "CASE WHEN" statement?

Tags: postgresql

I have such postresql query:

```
SELECT * , u.image AS image_name, k.id AS cat_id,
   CASE WHEN s.web_site!="" THEN s.web_site
   ELSE 'Not available' END AS v_site
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN comments s ON s.user_id = u.id WHERE u.id = '1547'
```

Query result:

```
users     | name    | v_site
----------+---------+---------------
ali       | hassan  | www.domain.com
turqut    | sandra  | www.somesite.com
emil      | azizov  | www.website.com
```

As u see I get website name like that **www.domain.com**. But I want to get that with  HTML  hyperlink tag: **<a href='www.domain.com'>www.domain.com
</a>**

How can I do that?

Comment: Is not `!=''` equal to `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @EmilAzizov: No, because '' is NOT NULL as well. So IS NOT NULL would include all rows where the column web_site contains a string of length zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!= ""` is invalid SQL syntax. Strings are delimited with a single qutoe.

```
SELECT *, 
       u.image AS image_name, 
       k.id AS cat_id,
       CASE 
         WHEN s.web_site != '' THEN '<a href="'||s.web_site||'">'||s.web_site||'</a>'
         ELSE 'Not available' 
       END AS v_site
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN comments s ON s.user_id = u.id WHERE u.id = '1547'
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.  I checked but  I got 0 (zero) instead of <a href="somesite">somesite</a>

Comment: Do you mean you get the value `0` for that column, or do you mean you get zero rows?

Comment: I mean I get value 0 for that column

Comment: Then you are not running the same statement. It's not possible to get `0` as the output of my CASE statement.

Comment: Believe or not I get zero :((